# Why m I getting this error in django urls?

Tags: django

[image]I am very new to Django and still trying to understand most things. l am currently working on a project where I need to add a details page for each link. 
But I am getting the following error.
Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /discover/

Reverse for 'disc-details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['discover/(?P<discover_id>[0-9]+)/']
```

Following is my urls patterns for app:

```
url(r'discover/$', views.discover, name = 'discover'),
url(r'discover/(?P<discover_id>[0-9]+)/', views.disc_details, name = 'disc-details'),
```

and my views.py look something like:

```
def discover(request):
    disc = Discover.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/discover.html', {'disc': disc})

def disc_details(request, discover_id):
    dis = get_object_or_404(Discover, pk = discover_id)
    det = Discover.objects.get(pk = discover_id)
    return render(request, 'main/discDetails.html', {'det': det, 'dis': dis})
```

Whats happening here is discover is a html page containing various links and each link should have its on disc_details section.
My html section has the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href='{% url 'main:disc-details' dis.id%}' class = "detail-link">Details</a>
```

Help me fix this and please provide an explanation.

Comment: The error is in the `discover.html`, it looks like the the `dis` variable does not exists there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context variable name is `disc`:

```
def discover(request):
    disc = Discover.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/discover.html', {'disc': disc})
```

So you should use `disc` in `discover.html` template also. Note you should iterate over `disc` values to get disc objects:

```
{% for el in disc %}
    '{% url 'main:disc-details' el.id %}'
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked. Now can you explain this in simple language. (why are we looping ?)

Comment: @ArjunKashyap we need to loop over `disc` since it contains multiple disc objects actually. Django's queryset `Discover.objects.all()` will give you list of discs. So you need to use loop to get access for each disc separately.

Comment: So I tried the loop method which worked when I added one entry in the database. Yet when I add more than one (say 2) it is showing two details (in a single section where there is supposed to be only one) link and when I click on them it takes me to the first database entry object. (Hope I made myself clear). I am adding a picture